# A function is mutating an object before being called: how is it possible?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, lodash

I've got a quite strange js question. I've  got a Vue component (but I think Vue is not important here). It has a data property called `current_query`. On a method that responds to an event, I want to modify that property. Using Lodash here. And there's a really curious behaviour. Say `this.current_query` is initially == `{ test: 500 }`. Say also that `'field'` parameter is `'test'`. By 'unsetting' it from `current_query`, in fact I'll empty current_query itself. Perfect. Thing is, that (only) when using unset, if I log current_query **before** calling unset, I'll get an empty object. How is it possible?

```
  on_applied_option_click(field){
    console.log(this.current_query); // gives { test: 500 } (OK)
  }, // end click

  on_applied_option_click(field){
    console.log(this.current_query); // gives empty object only if, and when, using _.unset  (??)
    _.unset(this.current_query, field);
    console.log(this.current_query); // gives empty object as well  (OK)
  }, // end click
```

I've found out that if I use `_.omit` instead, it all goes fine:

```
  on_applied_option_click(field){
    console.log(this.current_query); // gives { test: 500 }  (OK)
    this.current_query = _.omit(this.current_query, field);
    console.log(this.current_query); // gives empty object, which at this point is fine
  }, // end click
```

Why? The only thing I can say is that _.unset mutates the objects while _.omit creates new ones. But still, I think it's quite impossible that _.unset is going to mutate the object before even getting called (???). Never seen a thing like this. Has anyone some good explanation of this strange behaviour?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing `console.log(this.current_query)`, try `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.current_query))`. That logs reliably the state of `this.currenty_query` at the time of logging, and not possibly some state afterwards.

And that should solve the confusion.